# How to change default upload dir?

Tags: uploads, directory

I managed to change my default upload directory by using dayly upload dir plugin.

Now i can upload in year /month /day   the only problem is i used the default upload dir for so long that my old images are not working.

I need a code that can help me to do the y/m/d style if post published day is after 2017/01/01

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any plugins for it.
Using default option on page `wp-admin/options-media.php` you can change organizing files way and all your media would still working.

[image]

Comment: no dude i know dat ..i want to organize it month-year-then day...but only for new posts that i am going to post .....pls this problem i have its very anoying...HEEEEELLLLLLP

Comment: Have you tried this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-upload-dir/?